# Can't get response body in Axios with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, es6-promise

My frontend code:

```
const user = useSelector(selectUser)
function getWatchLater(name){
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/watchlater', {user:name})
  .then((response)=>{
    // console.log(response.data)
    setWatchLater(response.data)
  })
}
```

The `user` variable holds the username and the function sends that username to the backend to get the data. Don't worry, the `user` variable does hold the username, i have checked it thoroughly.

My backend code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

app.get("/watchlater", (request, response)=>{
    const user = request.body.user;
    //console.log(user);
});
```

So basically, it will get the username and run the query. The problem is it does not get the username at all from the frontend. I tried console logging the variable `user` but to no avail. It returns empty.

Comment: I tired putting the functions in the frontend in a useEffect hook but it does not work either.

Comment: You can [edit] your post if you need to add more info. Your express route never responds to the request (and yes, the frontend should be in a useEffect or you'll probably get an infinite loop). There's no payload for GET requests--add the information to the query parameters or path. I suggest a basic express/ReactJS tutorial which will surely cover these things.

Comment: A GET request doesn't generally have a body - the semantics aren't defined, and the second argument to `axios.get` is **not** the request body.

Comment: Your `getWatchLater` function runs an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in the `axios.get()` function is expecting a **config** object. Checkout the axios documentations on [instance method](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) and [request config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config).

In short, in the frontend part, pass your payload into the `data` field of the config object, as shown in the example below.

```
const config = {
  headers: { Authorization: token },
  data: { user:name }
}
const response = await axios.get(`${url}`, config)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send parameter using params object of config in case of get request. Your frontend request should change to this,

```
const user = useSelector(selectUser)
function getWatchLater(name){
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/watchlater', { params: { user: name }
}).then((response)=>{
    // console.log(response.data)
    setWatchLater(response.data)
  })
}
```

In your express endpoint you should receive it as,

```
app.get("/watchlater", (request, response)=>{
    const user = request.params.user;
    //console.log(user);
});
```